# ZF2/PHP - How to extract Scalar Record from a Query and use as Parameter of Where Clause of Second Query?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

**Info**

I have an application where I want to query a table to be able to get out the record with the smallest id.  To simplify my understanding I composed two queries in two table methods.

I am able to query the database with a hard coded scalar but can not query based on the queried scalar from another query.

**Question**

How do I get a scalar value extracted from from a query in Zend Framework 2 and use the value as an input to the where clause of another (main) query?

**Code**

```
   public function getMinActionItemID()
    {
        $select = new Select();
        $select->from('actionitems', array('MinActionItemID'))->columns(array('MinActionItemID' => new Expression('min(ActionItemID)')));
        $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
        $resultSet->buffer();
        return $resultSet;
    }

public function getFirstActionItem()
{       
    var_dump($this->getMinActionItemID());
    $select = new Select();
    $select->from('actionitems')->where(array('ActionItemID' => $this->getMinActionItemID()));
    $row = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);        

    if (!$row) {
        throw new Exception("Action Item Not Found");
    }

    return $row;

}
```

I am able to get the following from the query but am unable to get out the scalar value from the object below which is returned from `getFirstActionItemID()` and pass into the where clause of the `getFirstActionItem()` method.

```
  object(Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet)[288]
  protected 'count' => int 1
  protected 'dataSource' => 
    object(Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Result)[266]
      protected 'statementMode' => string 'forward' (length=7)
      protected 'fetchMode' => int 2
      protected 'resource' => 
        object(PDOStatement)[267]
          public 'queryString' => string 'SELECT min(ActionItemID) AS `MinActionItemID` FROM `actionitems`' (length=64)
      protected 'options' => null
      protected 'currentComplete' => boolean true
      protected 'currentData' => 
        array (size=1)
          'MinActionItemID' => string '1' (length=1)
      protected 'position' => int 0
      protected 'generatedValue' => string '0' (length=1)
      protected 'rowCount' => int 1
  protected 'fieldCount' => int 1
  protected 'position' => int 0
```

EDIT

I ended up abandoning my approach and used the answers provided.  I also preserved the  `getMinActionItemID()` so that I would use it for boundary checking when I navigate to the first and last record and try to go next or previous in my application.

With some investigation through the intellisense, I finally found a way to get out the desired scalar. In hindsight I found both the answer and this code to solve my problem of navigation (one record at a time).

### How To Get Scalar From Query

**Answer**

```
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Result;

/* @var $resultSet ResultSet */
    /* @var $dataSource Result */
    public function getMinActionItemID()
    {
        $select = new Select();
        $select->from('actionitems', array('MinActionItemID'))->columns(array('MinActionItemID' => new Expression('min(ActionItemID)')));
        $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
        $dataSource = $resultSet->getDataSource();
        return $dataSource->getResource()->fetchAll()[0]['MinActionItemID'];
    }
```

**Usage**

```
public function getNextActionItem($id)
{

    if ($id == $this->getMaxActionItemID())
    {
        return $this->getActionItem($id);
    }

    $select = new Select();
    $select->from('actionitems')
           ->where("ActionItemID > $id")
           ->order('ActionItemID')
           ->limit(1);
    $row = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);

    if (!$row) {
        throw new Exception ("Action Item Not Found");
    }

    return $row;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to Extract Scalar From an Arbitrary Query from $resultSet in two steps.**

```
 $dataSource = $resultSet->getDataSource();
 $minActionItemID =  $dataSource->getResource()->fetchAll()[0]['MinActionItemID'];  //Note: [0] is the first record and ['MinActionItemID'] is the field name of the custom query
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing this in one query, here's how (assume that $table, is an instance of your table gateway):

```
    use Zend\Db\Sql\Expression;
    use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;

    ...

    $set   = $table->select( function( Select $s ){

        $sub = new Select('actionitems');
        $sub->columns( [ 'min_id' => new Expression( 'MIN(ActionItemID)') ] );

        $s->columns(['*'])
            ->where([ 'ActionItemID' => $sub ])
                ->limit( 1 );
    });

    var_dump( $set->current() );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want select row with min ActionItemID you can order with ActionItemID and set limit to 1.

```
public function getFirstActionItem()
{
    $select = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select();
    $select->order('ActionItemID');
    $select->limit(1);

    $row = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select)->current();

    if (!$row) {
        throw new Exception('Action Item Not Found');
    }

    return $row;
}
```